# impossible Java method call behavior

Tags: java

I have a little bit of code in a class running in Java 1.7.0_17 and Jboss 4.2.3GA under windows. The code does this:

```
Date newNextDate = inBetween(currentDate, nextDate, start);
print("newNextDate=" + newNextDate);
```

The inbetween does a fairly simply comparison:

```
private Date inBetween(Date start, Date end, Date test) {
    ...
    Date contains = t.contains(test) ? test : end;
    print("returning contains=" + contains);
    return contains;
}
```

The exact implementation contains is not relevant IMHO, because in the end results in a java.util.Date being assigned to the contains variable. The output on stdout is:

```
16:44:56,153 INFO returning contains=Tue Apr 30 23:59:59 CEST 2013
16:44:56,153 INFO newNextDate=null
```

And this where where the mystery begins: 
1. just prior to the return statement the contains variable has a value
2. after returning the collecting variable is null

How in the world is this possible?

- Yes, we've checked if exactly this inbetween method is called, otherwise it would not have printed the output.
- No, there is no instance variable with the same name. But even if, there is nothing happening in between.
- No, we cannot debug the process, because it only occurs on our production servers and is not reproducable on development.

The strangest thing is, it only occurs here, nowhere else in the 1.000.000 lines of code.

Comment: There in your code where the 'print' is, print a stack trace. `Exception e = new NullPointerException(); System.printstacktrace(e);` (warning: pseudo-java) and make sure there hasn't been an injection of a proxy of some sort around the `inBetween()` method. (Obscure but possible.)

Comment: you can actually attach to the jvm and remote debug your production server. http://java.dzone.com/articles/how-debug-remote-java-applicat

Comment: Use debug and iterate step by step. Add breakpoints where necessary and look at the values. You definitely have an error somewhere.

Comment: or the code you are reviewing is _not_ the revision used to build what was deployed in production

Comment: Can you enable some form of logging on the production server?

Comment: This might be worth a shot - Get a copy of the deployed package (jar/war/ear...) and decompile the classes in question using JD GUI and make sure that it's the code that you think is being executed.

Comment: it's not unthinkable that it's a VM bug.

Comment: Right now everything points toward a loop unrolling bug in the JVM

Comment: We've setup a copy production environment so we don't mess with anything and had a batch request the same page over and over all night long (about 50.000 times by now). Nothing is going wrong, but exactly the same page on the original production environment is showing the behavior caused by the variable problem.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you have overloaded your inBetween and that gets called:

```
private Date inBetween(long start, Date end, Date test) {
     Date result = null;
     inBetween(new Date(start), end, test);
     return result;
}
```

Or something similarly typical. A `catch ... return null`.

The only other technical way would be to have an AOP interceptor doing a wrong caching (memoization?) or so. Unlikely.

Comment: The method is private and within the same class, so it cannot be overloaded. But we've checked and there is only one. In debug you can trace the call to this method (but then it works fine).

Comment: Impossible code, when really no final block, no other `print("returning contains=" + ...); return null;` in the `...`. _(**override** = via inheritance have a method with same name and parameter types; **overload** = have a method with same name but different parameter types)_